# nginx is getting GET / request although its wrong

Tags: nginx, docker

So I run a nginx container with docker-compose:

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: webserver_nginx
    hostname: nginx
    stop_grace_period: 1m30s

    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -sf http://127.0.0.1/ -o /dev/null || exit 1"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 40s

    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80

    volumes:
      # Service Restriction with password
      - ./.credentials/.htpasswd:/var/.credentials/.htpasswd

      # Nginx Configurations
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./proxy_params:/etc/nginx/proxy_params
      - ./conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d

      #Nginx serve static files
      - /var/backups/off:/var/web_data/off


      # Nginx Logging
      - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx

    networks:
      - webserver_network

networks:
  webserver_network:
    external: true
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

my nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

and config for my container:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name name.com;

  location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://off:4000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_read_timeout 100;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
  location /static {
    alias /var/web_data/off/collectstatic;
  }

  location /media {
    alias /var/web_data/off/upload;
  }

  location / {
    return 404;
  }
}
```

so whenever i try to request `http://name.com/admin` i get this kind of log from access.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022:15:53:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.74.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022:15:55:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.74.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022:15:56:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.74.0" "-"
```

and i get 502 Gateway error from nginx on the browser
even when i try to access main site like `http://name.com/` i keep getting 502 Error
my container compose is like:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  offch:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: deploy/beta/Dockerfile
      args:
        WORKING_DIR: /app
    container_name: off
    hostname: django
    restart: 'always'

    command: gunicorn -c deploy/beta/configs/gunicorn/conf.py --chdir api api.wsgi:application

    volumes:
      # Source Code of project
      - .:/app
      # Collect Static files
      - /var/backups/offch/collectstatic:/collectstatic
      # Media Files (Uploads)
      - /var/backups/offch/upload:/app/media/upload
      - /var/log/upstart:/var/log/upstart

    stop_grace_period: 1m30s

    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://127.0.0.1:4000"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 40s

    ports:
      - "4000:4000"

    networks:
      - webserver_network

networks:
  webserver_network:
    external: true
```

Btw i can access the site through ip and port i only have this problem with nginx.

Comment: hi, it matters what you want to use. that means that you should use the 404 first and then the admin directive imho

Comment: @djdomi hello, thanks for answering but it did not work im still getting the same log from nginx access.log, i already used this config on another server and i only have this problem here

Comment: what happened while you disable the last part, and does not work is not an error description ;) if you change the configuration or environment, you need to reflect the changes also on the question, please show the output of `nginx -T`